# Credential manager ruby on rails accessing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and I am trying to run the credential manager to edit the file to add in a google maps api key i have for an app however its saying the command credentials:edit does not exist as per below any suggestions would be most helpful I installed Ubuntu and ruby on rails this week but still to get this working 100%

I tried

```
rails credentials:edit
```

in the terminal window in the path of my project but the error it is showing is below.

> rails credentials:edit Error: Command 'credentials:edit' not
>   recognized Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
>
> The most common rails commands are:

**Edit**
I am using rails version 4.2.10 and ruby version 2.5 1p57 (revision 63029)

Still not working
[image]

Comment: This is only available in Rails 5.2 and up

Answer (score 0):

To run the command you are trying to run you need the **rails wrapper** which, in ubuntu and most linux distros, is in ~/bin so you need to run

```
bin/rails credentials:edit
```

If that doesn't work for you then you could try

```
bundle exec rails credentials:edit
```

You might find this article of interest https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2

if you run `bin/rails` you run the wrapper which does a multitude of things for you

e.g. `bin/rails about` can be very interesting it will check all your dependencies are OK amongst other things that `rails about` won't do it also speeds things up for you

Comment: I can run commands like rails s though from anywhere is there something special that credentials have to be run from the bin?

Comment: i still get the following david@david-Virtual-Machine:~/sites/theflow/bin$ bundle exec rails credentials:edit
Error: Command 'credentials:edit' not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

Comment: @rogue39nin yes there is, as I said you need to run the rails wrapper not the rails command I have updated my answer

Comment: @rogue39nin Did you try `bin/rails credentials:edit` it works for me. If not for you, what rails version are you using? I think this is for rails 5 onwards

Comment: still didnt work see my edits above with version numbers added.

Comment: @rogue39nin kit will never work, as per my answer introduced in rails 5.2,

Comment: @rogue39nin Nice one

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Rails credentials is available after Rails version-5.2 [Check here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html).

After that if you wish to edit and create the rails credentials , follow this steps ..

1. `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`  : By this command this will create the credentials file in the rails project
2. `rails credentials:show` : you can check the created rails credentials
3. `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` : By using this you may edit the rails credentials in your specified text editor , use can also use following command .

   - To edit in the Sublime : `EDITOR="subl --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`
   - For Atom : `EDITOR="atom --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`
   - For Console GNU nano editor :  `EDITOR="nano" bin/rails credentials:edit`
   - For MacOs editor : `EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`
4. Now save the credentials and Use secured credentials By using the 
   `<%= Rails.application.credentials[:development][:database][:username] %>`
5. And it's done , save your code and check the key/value in the rails project .

   Happy Codding :)

---

Useful links :

[Ruby guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials)

[Medium blog](https://medium.com/@kirill_shevch/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc)